# useState returning an object when adding to previous state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I have a button and onClick I'd like it to add 20 to the previous offset. However, when I do the following, i get an object for some reason:

```
const [ offset, setOffset ] = React.useState(20);

const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_FEED, {
 variables: {
   offset: offset,
   limit: 10
 },
 fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
});

<button onClick={(prevOffset) => setOffset(prevOffset + 20)>Next</button>
```

Upon clicking next, the request throws a 400 and the browser says these are the variables:

```
variables   {…}
limit   10
offset  "[object Object]20"
```

If I just do:

```
<button onClick={() => setOffset(20)>Next</button>
```

It works successfully, but I'm stuck with an offset of 20.

Comment: Try passing a function to `setOffset` instead? `setOffset(prevOffset => prevOffset + 20)`

Comment: That is because first parameter of onClick is event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in the `onClick` `event` parameter. Which is, in fact, an object...

`setState` allows you to pass a function where the param is the old state. I think that is what you meant to do.

Try below.

```
const [ offset, setOffset ] = React.useState(20);

const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_FEED, {
 variables: {
   offset: offset,
   limit: 10
 },
 fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
});

<button onClick={() => setOffset(prevOffset => prevOffset + 20)>Next</button>
```